# How to determine an initial guess value and to minimize to find parameters

Tags: python, math, optimization, minimize

[image: first one is 'x' values and 2nd column is 'events' values]Please correct my code if there is anything wrong. All i want to do is to minimize the function to find parameters 'a' and 'b' and also how to determine an initial guess just by looking the function.

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd        

data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Bza\\Documents\\Project\\Python files\\Default Dataset.csv", header=None)    

x=data.iloc[:,0]    
events=data.iloc[:,1]    

def f(params):    
    a, b = params    
    s=0.0    
    for i in range(0,71):    
        s+=((events[i]-x[i]**(a+b*np.log(x[i]))))/np.sqrt(events[i])    
        return s    
guess=[1,1]    
from scipy.optimize import minimize    
result=minimize(f,guess,method='Nelder-Mead')    
print (result)
```

By the way, the function is Chi squared function. In mathematica, i get -1.2 and -0.045 respectively for a and b.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your Default Dataset.csv file?

Comment: I have posted now